# Можно ли отсортировать таблицу во время ее создания?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет.
Есть такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE EUR_USD(
 TICKET text,
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY date,
 HOUR_MIN_SEC time,
 OPEN_PRICE  numeric(10,5),
 HIGH_PRICE  numeric(10,5),
 LOW_PRICE  numeric(10,5),
 CLOSE_PRICE  numeric(10,5),
 VOLUME  double precision,
);
```

Вопрос:
Возможно ли отсортировать любой из столбцов(например по возрастанию или убиванию) именно во время создания таблицы а не после этого процесса?

Если делаю это после создания таблицы например такой командой:

```
SELECT t.*, CTID 
FROM public.eur_usd t 
ORDER BY year_month_day ASC, hour_min_sec ASC;
```

То как я понимаю это влияет только на результат вывода а не на структуру самой таблицы.
(Поправьте меня если я не прав, Сам верстальщик..)

P.S. Буду благодарен за конструктивные советы.

Comment: По-моему вам нужно просто создать соответствующий индекс, чтобы PostgreSQL использовал индекс для сортировки (`ORDER BY year_month_day, hour_min_sec`).

Comment: Пример можите привести(синтаксиса) самый примитивный на моей таблице - как упорядочить по индексу таблицу или ее колонку?

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. Идёт вставка записей в условную середину таблицы. Если сохранять порядок, то все записи ниже вставленной нужно сдвигать. Это значит, что нужно будет каждый раз физически перезаписывать эти записи. И база данных покроется неимоверными тормозами

Comment: Ничего не надо сдвигать. Максимум - расщепится блок, но вероятность этого события не зависит от физического или логического порядков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Postgresql не поддерживает упорядоченные (`clustered`) таблицы.

Есть команда [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html) которая может разово отсортировать данные таблицы по индексу, но в дальнейшей работе сортировка поддерживаться не будет.

`SELECT`, естественно, не меняет физический порядок строк.

---

Сразу встречный вопрос: для чего? По стандарту `SQL` вы обязаны явно указывать сортировку, если хотите получить результат отсортированным. Иначе СУБД имеет право не соблюдать порядок результата. Для пропуска возможно дорогостоящего процесса сортировки данных вам нужен индекс, который даст отсортированный набор данных. И достаточный `shared_buffers` чтобы не ходить за данными на диски, а работать в RAM

Comment: >> По стандарту SQL вы обязаны явно указывать сортировку, если хотите получить результат отсортированным. Иначе СУБД имеет право не соблюдать порядок результата
------------
Не знал - спасибо за инфу.

Comment: Мне это нужно было за тем что бы в Pycharm я мог наблюдать таблицу.
Там 100 000 000 строк +-
и мне надо понимать в некоторых местах что там к чему - но когда я начинаю листать постранично по 500 строк данные и потом отматывать обратно на предыдущие страницы - у меня весь порядок сбрасывается и превращается в хаос.
(который мне на данном этапе не допустим.)

Comment: И еще один момент.
Я собственно вот почему хотел упорядочить во время создания таблицу.
Мне необходимо из миллионов строк выдергивать максимально быстро несколько десятков.
Как я понимаю во время выдергивания происходит процесс упорядочивания который забирает время.
Собственно поэтому я и хотел изначально упорядочить таблицу что бы в дальнейшем при каждом выдергивании(а они могут происходить несколько раз(или даже десятков раз) за секунду.) это время не отжиралось.

Comment: Чтобы быстро читать отсортированными несколько десяткой строк - вам нужен подходящий индекс. В каком порядке данные в таблице при этом - неважно. Но и в запросе order by должен быть указан обязательно, если нужен определённый порядок.

Answer (score 1):

После созадния по этой команде таблицы и экзекьюшена, юзай https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html создания индекса для данной таблицы с опциями сортировки. Таким образом, достигнешь цели